# PHP using get_where clause in Codeigniter not passing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

Hi All I'm new to Codeigniter, I'm trying to get all data relating to the account_id passed from a previous page.

I'm passing the account_id but not passing the name field associated with the account_id.  The name field is blank.

I'm getting an error:

Here is my code for the controller:

```
function input($account_id = '', $name = ''){
   if((int)$account_id > 0){
      $query = $this->db->select('name', $name);
      $query = $this->db->get_where('db_accounts', array('account_id' => $account_id));

      $data['account'] = $query;
      $data['fname']['value']   = $name;
      $data['faccount_id']['value'] = $account_id;
      $data['name']        = '';
      $data['account_id']  = '';
  }

  $this->load->view('manage/input',$data);      
}
```

Here is my input view form:

```
<?php

   $data = array(
          'name'  => $fname['value'],
          'account_id' => $faccount_id['value']
        );

echo '<form action="/manage/edit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">';
echo form_hidden($data);

echo $account_id .' Account ID'.
    form_input($faccount_id); 
echo $name .' Name'.
    form_input($fname); 

$data = array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Update Account', 'class' => 'submit');
echo form_submit($data);

  ?>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  In the form variable 'name' is blank but the 'account_id' is passing the value.

Answer (score 3):

i believe `get_where` just preps your query

`$query->row_array()` should return your result as an array

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('db_accounts', array('account_id' => $account_id));
$result = $query->row_array();
```

For the second part of your question it looks like there is a lot going on.  What is the value of `$name` in your `input` function? Are you actually passing a value to `input`?  Make sure that name is set in your `input` function or else it will just be an empty string.

Comment: +1, it looks like you are missing the code like above that runs that query.

Comment: How am I passing the account_id to the next page and not the other fields?

Comment: because you already have the account id - that was passed into the function. ive edited the answer above with comment to highlight.

Comment: the $name is set in the input function function input($account_id = '', $name = '') See above in my controller info.

Answer (score 2):

Occupied from documentation:

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

So replace

```
$query = $this->db->select('name', $name);
```

with

```
$this->db->select('name', $name); // No need to assign it to a variable
```

Then `$this->db->get_where();` executes the query and return the entire query object you need to fetch the result from it.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('db_accounts', array('account_id' => $account_id));
$result = $query->row_array(); //For single row
$result = $query->result_array(); //For more than one row
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with the help of djjjuk.

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('db_accounts', array('account_id' => $account_id));
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
     $row = $query->row_array();

   } 

  $data['account'] = $row;

  $data['fname']['value']   = $row['name'];
  $data['faccount_id']['value'] = $account_id;
  $data['name']        = '';
  $data['account_id']  = '';
}

  $this->load->view('manage/input',$data);      

 }
```